# How to monitor syslog and get alerted when there is a certain entry?

Tags: scripts, software-recommendation, syslog, monitoring, notify-send

There is a certain error which is always the same and I am getting in syslog, however I am not really sure what the error is being caused by so I would like to get alerted immediately whenever it occurs. Preferably I would like something like a script to monitor syslog for any lines containing that certain message, and if it is detected for it to immediately alert me through `notify-send` and then to log it in a file. I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20. How can I achieve this through a script? Or is there some software that would allow me to do this?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju: Oh right, sorry, a lot was happening and I forgot to do that!

Comment: You can check [fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban) source for this kind of implementation. It looks for specific strings in syslog and bans host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, a script, in Python:

Checks file for changes every 5 seconds, if changed, it checks for the string. If string is found:

- the line in which it was found along with the current time is printed
- *[optional]* notifies using `notify-send`
- *[optional]* plays the default alert sound

Usage:

```
python3 LogMonitor.py [log file] [string to watch]
```

Optional arguments, to be put after the above

- `beep` and/or `notify` -- this will cause the script to beep and/or notify (using `notify-send`) in addition to printing the message

So, if I want to watch `/var/log/auth.log` for SSH and make a beep sound *and* notify me, I will:

```
python3 LogMonitor.py /var/log/auth.log SSH beep notify
```

Raw download (*Right Click* → *Save link as*): [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/bharadwaj-raju/ce9b40068e9b0dee18231a7e1553b368/raw/c5df0a7320d303b3173e260017d7f8aafde2c023/LogMonitor.py)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import subprocess
import collections
import time
import mmap

try:

    LOG_FILE = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
    WATCH_FOR = sys.argv[2]

except:

    sys.stderr.write(
        'Usage: %s [log file] [string to watch for]' % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

def action():

    if 'beep' in sys.argv:

        subprocess.Popen(['paplay', '/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/notifications/Mallet.ogg'])

    if 'notify' in sys.argv:

        subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', 'LogMonitor', 'Found!'])

    print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'), 'Found! \n', i)

# basic Python implementation of Unix tail

def tail(file, n):

    with open(file, "r") as f:

        f.seek (0, 2)           # Seek @ EOF
        fsize = f.tell()        # Get Size
        f.seek (max (fsize-1024, 0), 0) # Set pos @ last n chars
        lines = f.readlines()       # Read to end

    lines = lines[-n:]    # Get last 10 lines

    return lines


print(
    'Watching of ' + LOG_FILE + ' for ' + WATCH_FOR +
    ' started at ' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'))

mtime_last = 0

while True:

    mtime_cur = os.path.getmtime(LOG_FILE)

    if mtime_cur != mtime_last:

        for i in tail(LOG_FILE, 5):

            if WATCH_FOR.lower() in i.lower():

                action()

    mtime_last = mtime_cur

    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Did the script help?